# Join command for two big files based on one column gives empty output

Tags: bash, join, awk

I am having a big problem joining two (massive) files, since I have tried all the possible combinations of the join command and other AWK options that I saw in other users' questions, but the outcome is always the same: it doesn't generate an output (and I know there are field in common). To illustrate the problem, I will leave part of the files here:
FILE 1:

```
SiiA    lcl|NC_003197.2_prot_NP_463122.1_4111   100.000 100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIENKTKSTAQNSGANDDSNPNEIVNKEVNTQDVSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKTDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTYKIKAWLEDKINSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
SiiA    lcl|NC_010102.1_prot_WP_000389232.1_4169    99.048  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIENKTKSTAQNSGANDDSNPNEIVNKEVNTQDVSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKTDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTHKIKAWLEDKTNSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
SiiA    lcl|CP052796.1_prot_QJV25805.1_4154 97.143  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIESKTKSTAQNSGANDNSNANEIINKEVNTQDMSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKTDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTHKIKAWLEDKINSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
SiiA    lcl|NZ_CP009559.1_prot_WP_000389229.1_1106  97.143  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIENKTKSTAQNNGANDNSNANEIVNKEVNTQDVSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKTDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTHKIEAWLEDKTNSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
SiiA    lcl|NZ_CP029897.1_prot_WP_000389235.1_4284  97.143  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIENKTKSTAQNSGANDNSNANEIVNKEVNTQDVSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKIDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTHKIEAWLEDKTNSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
SiiA    lcl|NZ_CP053416.1_prot_WP_079774927.1_2027  77.619  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMLIMYDNSIKVYKTNIEKHANSKDEKSGDNKKENTNEKVENETISKDSSAESTEMSGKEIGIYDIADDQRIDITSEEKELVITYRGRLRSFSKEDLNKITVWLEDKANSNLLIEMIIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSTASSSTSKAIITTTNKKVPE
SiiB    lcl|NC_003197.2_prot_NP_463123.1_4112   100.000 100 MKYINHYRYLFVCFFLAILPFFALSFPGIREYVFDNFMVSAIYNGVIIAIYITGSLCALFTILKNISAKDILIAQDASRKNSILSNLNQVLFAGESKQCDFNLLMELDDNVSTARNQRLSFIMSCSNVSTLVGLLGTFAGLSITIGSIGNLLSSPSDVGGDNASNTLNMIVTMVASLSEPLKGMNTAFVSSIYGVVCAILLTSQSVFVRSSYSLVSTEIKKLKIISNRANNKQRSLRVESETLVEFKELFKAFFDNYLTVENLRTQDEEKKREMLSDSFVTLQNRLLDNSAKLEQISTLIDGYLVSSNENLKKLSDGVITITSRLSEGNILLADNNARLEAMSTIQNIIDKKNDSIMTSVDKCYQESLSHGKTINDIAAGSADISHTLDGLRKEMDEDMNNVHLALSDLSATDKKIIANTKEISAEMVSYRDTYMPLMEKITSMHQEIVKQRLLNKEEKNED
```

FILE 2:

```
Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Typhimurium_LT2 >lcl|NC_003197.2_prot_NP_463122.1_4111
Salmonella_bongori >lcl|NZ_CP053416.1_prot_WP_000427862.1_2024
Salmonella_bongori >lcl|NZ_CP053416.1_prot_WP_079774928.1_2025
Salmonella_bongori >lcl|NZ_CP053416.1_prot_WP_000168315.1_2026
Salmonella_bongori >lcl|NZ_CP053416.1_prot_WP_079774927.1_2027
Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Typhimurium_LT2 >lcl|NC_003197.2_prot_NP_463123.1_4112
Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Typhimurium_LT2 >lcl|NC_003197.2_prot_NP_463124.1_4113
```

And the expected output would be:

```
SiiA    Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Typhimurium_LT2  lcl|NC_003197.2_prot_NP_463122.1_4111   100.000 100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIENKTKSTAQNSGANDDSNPNEIVNKEVNTQDVSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKTDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTYKIKAWLEDKINSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
SiiA    Salmonella_bongori  lcl|NZ_CP053416.1_prot_WP_079774927.1_2027  77.619  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMLIMYDNSIKVYKTNIEKHANSKDEKSGDNKKENTNEKVENETISKDSSAESTEMSGKEIGIYDIADDQRIDITSEEKELVITYRGRLRSFSKEDLNKITVWLEDKANSNLLIEMIIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSTASSSTSKAIITTTNKKVPE
SiiB    Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Typhimurium_LT2  lcl|NC_003197.2_prot_NP_463123.1_4112   100.000 100 MKYINHYRYLFVCFFLAILPFFALSFPGIREYVFDNFMVSAIYNGVIIAIYITGSLCALFTILKNISAKDILIAQDASRKNSILSNLNQVLFAGESKQCDFNLLMELDDNVSTARNQRLSFIMSCSNVSTLVGLLGTFAGLSITIGSIGNLLSSPSDVGGDNASNTLNMIVTMVASLSEPLKGMNTAFVSSIYGVVCAILLTSQSVFVRSSYSLVSTEIKKLKIISNRANNKQRSLRVESETLVEFKELFKAFFDNYLTVENLRTQDEEKKREMLSDSFVTLQNRLLDNSAKLEQISTLIDGYLVSSNENLKKLSDGVITITSRLSEGNILLADNNARLEAMSTIQNIIDKKNDSIMTSVDKCYQESLSHGKTINDIAAGSADISHTLDGLRKEMDEDMNNVHLALSDLSATDKKIIANTKEISAEMVSYRDTYMPLMEKITSMHQEIVKQRLLNKEEKNED
```

I have tried from using the join command:
`join -j2 -o1.1,2.1,1.2,1.3,1.4, 1.5 <(sort -k2 file1) <(sort -k2 file2)`(which doesn't work since it says that I am not using the command properly)
`join -2 1 -2 2 <(sort -k2 file1) <(sort -k2 file2)`

And some option with AWK:
`awk '{if (NR==FNR) {a[$2]=$1; next} if ($2 in a) {print $1, a[$2] $2, $3, $4, $5}}' file1 file2`
or
`awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next} a[$2]==$2{print $0, a[$2]}' file1 file2`

I don't what else to try, or where else I can read about this since nothing seems to work.
Thank you in advance for you time :)

Comment: Debug it, e.g. by divide and conquer. Remove half the columns from each file. Do you still have the problem? If no start over but remove the other half of the columns. Do you still have the problem? If yes, remove half the colums from the new file. Do you still have the problem? Repeat until you either no longer have the problem (you'll probably figure out the solution yourself along the way) or have a minimal pair of files you can use for the [mcve] for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sample inputs the general issue with the `join -j2` is that field #2 in `file2` has an 'extra' prefix of `>`, eg:

```
# file1 / line #1 / field #2
lcl|NC_003197.2_prot_NP_463122.1_4111

# file2 / line #1 / field #2
>lcl|NC_003197.2_prot_NP_463122.1_4111
```

Because of the 'extra' `>` no joins can be made.

Short of adding (or removing?) the 'extra' `>` during pre-processing, one small change to OP's sample `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$1; next} (substr($2,2) in a) {$2=substr($2,2);print $0,a[$2]}' file1 file2
```

**NOTE:** one big issue with using `awk` arrays and 'massive' files is that you could hit an Out Of Memory (OOM) error (depends on actual volume of data that will need to be stored in the `awk` arrays).

---

---

Going back to pre-processing ... OP could look at stripping the `>` prefix from `file2's` 2nd field.

One idea using `sed` to strip out the first `>` it encounters in `file2` (assumes this will always be first character of field #2):

```
sed 's/>//' file2
```

Adding this into OP's sample `join`:

```
join -j2 -o1.1,2.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5 <(sort -k2 file1) <(sed 's/>//' file2|sort -k2)
```

Which generates:

```
SiiA Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Typhimurium_LT2 lcl|NC_003197.2_prot_NP_463122.1_4111 100.000 100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIENKTKSTAQNSGANDDSNPNEIVNKEVNTQDVSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKTDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTYKIKAWLEDKINSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
SiiB Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Typhimurium_LT2 lcl|NC_003197.2_prot_NP_463123.1_4112 100.000 100 MKYINHYRYLFVCFFLAILPFFALSFPGIREYVFDNFMVSAIYNGVIIAIYITGSLCALFTILKNISAKDILIAQDASRKNSILSNLNQVLFAGESKQCDFNLLMELDDNVSTARNQRLSFIMSCSNVSTLVGLLGTFAGLSITIGSIGNLLSSPSDVGGDNASNTLNMIVTMVASLSEPLKGMNTAFVSSIYGVVCAILLTSQSVFVRSSYSLVSTEIKKLKIISNRANNKQRSLRVESETLVEFKELFKAFFDNYLTVENLRTQDEEKKREMLSDSFVTLQNRLLDNSAKLEQISTLIDGYLVSSNENLKKLSDGVITITSRLSEGNILLADNNARLEAMSTIQNIIDKKNDSIMTSV  DKCYQESLSHGKTINDIAAGSADISHTLDGLRKEMDEDMNNVHLALSDLSATDKKIIANTKEISAEMVSYRDTYMPLMEKITSMHQEIVKQRLLNKEEKNED
SiiA Salmonella_bongori lcl|NZ_CP053416.1_prot_WP_079774927.1_2027 77.619 100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMLIMYDNSIKVYKTNIEKHANSKDEKSGDNKKENTNEKVENETISKDSSAESTEMSGKEIGIYDIADDQRIDITSEEKELVITYRGRLRSFSKEDLNKITVWLEDKANSNLLIEMIIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSTASSSTSKAIITTTNKKVPE
```

**NOTE:** OP's `join` format (`-o...`) will place single spaces between the fields while OP's desired output is showing multiple spaces (or are those tabs?); I'll leave it up to OP to work out the differences in white space.

Comment: Hello! Yes, short after posting the question, I found out there was de extra `>` in `File2`. I changed it and tried the join again, and it still doesn't work. I don't know what is failing there. With the AWK works perfectly now, thanks! :)

Comment: @AmandaJiménez if you remove the '>' from `file2`, your first `join` command works for me and produces the 3 desired rows (**NOTE:** make sure to remove the space in `1.4, 1.5`); my `join` command (above) also works when you remove the `>` from `file2`; at this point I'm guessing something else has changed with field #2 which is keeping it from being joined correctly ... ???

Comment: For some reason, the other day when I tried it, it still didn't work, but the syntax you suggested is working now. Ir works when I write in the terminal, but when I execute the script it gives me an error in that line. This is driving me crazy...